# Cannot auto scroll text in TextView

Tags: android, scroll, textview, autoscroll

I'm trying to have a auto scroll TextView when my text is too long. I followed every tutorial or tips posted here on stackoverflow (yes I readed a bunch of topics similar to this but no one fixed it).

So I have my activity layout like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

....

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/music_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Music Name"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />

....

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in OnCreate( ) I do that:

```
music_name.setSelected(true);
music_name.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

music_name is the TextView.

So even doing all that my TextView doesn't scroll. What could be wrong?

EDIT[NEW]: I noticed that it works only for the first time. The other times I change the text on the TextView it doesnt works anymore. What it could be doing that? I have thread (Timer) that wakes up every 50ms to update an SeekBar and other two TextViews, this could be blocking something?

Comment: Do you want it to scroll Horizontally or Vertically?

Comment: it would be better to scroll horizontally, but if it can only scroll vertically it would be ok

Answer (score 2):

`TextView` sometimes comes tricky when handling scrolling. The main attributes you've to set into your layout are the following:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

The `gravity` set to bottom will make your scrollbar descend to the bottom of your `TextView` everytime you append a line. So use that only if you want it to be that way.

The `music_name.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` statement is also needed.

This way it should work.

Comment: I changed that on my XML and it doesn't work. It just kept a static text missing part of text.

Comment: Is that TextView `singleLine` on purpose? If it has just one line, why do you need scrolling?

Comment: It was there because the original idea was to create a horizontal scroll with only one line. But deleting it from XML doesn't solves the problem too. 

It just makes the text change orientation because of the gravity="bottom" but the text doesn't auto scroll.

Comment: Just to clarify: By 'autoscroll' you mean that the textview automatically scrolls to the bottom of the content each time you call append on it? Are you adding enough text to make the scroll fire up? The way you've defined it, it just fires when it has to.

Comment: I was thinking of something that the text on the TextView keeps scrolling on infinite loop to show the entire text. I dont know if this is what TextView do, but Im trying to find this effect.

Comment: Then I would switch back to the `singleLine`d option, with vertical scrolling disabled, horizontal scroll enabled (or even disabled if you want), and the effect you're looking for is an attribute of `TextView` called `ellipsize`. What you want to do I think is the `marquee` effect. Simply set `android:ellipsize="marquee"` and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some animation, something like this scroll_textview_animation.xml in anim folder in the res:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="3000"
android:fromXDelta="200"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:toXDelta="-200" />
```

and onCreate or after setting the text:

```
music_name.startAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context,R.anim.scroll_textview_animation));
```

or you can start the animation on click:

```
music_name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            music_name.startAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context,R.anim.scroll_textview_animation));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="very long text to srollll abcdefghijklmnopqrstdaghlfj'ogjpsroshsrfjhrdjdjkdjdkjdk" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Comment: Full text is not visible , i mean it exceeds by " ... "

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```

And define addTextChangedListener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //some code here

    ScrollView scrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        // you can add a toast or whatever you want here
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,     int arg3) {
        //override stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int     arg3) {
        //override stub
    }

}) }
```